# Converse of laplace equation

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=u+iv$ and if $f(z)$ is analytic function, then $u$ and $v$ are harmonic i.e. satisfies Laplace equation, $\nabla^2u=0$. I learned that the converse is not true.
I dont understand why the converse is not true, and how they proved that the converse is not true. Can someone provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here is - compared to the Cauchy-Riemann equations - that the condition that $u,v$ are harmonic does not relate them to each other in any way at all. I can choose $u,v$ independently and still satisfy the condition.

You should be able to come up with an example yourself now, but I give one below if you need it.

---

So you just need to choose, say, $v=0$ for simplicity, and then pick some $u$ which isn't constant - that violates the CR equations. $f(x+iy)=x$ will do.